# Change ul::before selector when hover li:first-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have a problem.
I want to change de ::after color (#406394) to (#557EB7) when de first li element in the sub-menu is hovered. Can someone help me?

The ::after and the first-child li element in the sub-menu should look as only one element.

```css
.menu ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 200px;
}
.menu li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #406394;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #557EB7;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 9px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  display: block;
  background: #557EB7;
}
.menu li i {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  float: right;
}
.menu li a i.glyphicon {
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}
.menu li a:hover i.glyphicon {
  transform: rotate(540deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(540deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(540deg);
}
.dropdown-menu {
  top: 44px !important;
  left: 219px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background-color: #406394 !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  left: 233px !important;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
.dropdown-menu li:last-child {
  border: none !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 6px 20px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #557EB7 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu::after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #406394;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out all;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Empresa <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Quienes Somos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mision</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Políticas de calidad</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Instalaciones</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Equipo de Trabajo</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Instrumentos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do it using css because css cannot go upwards. You will have to use javascript

Answer (score -1):

You can target first li element using `.dropdown-menu li:first-of-type:hover`

Comment: And how does this relate to the problem, actually?